# C# Weird execution sequence

Tags: c#

Please help me understand this. I have this code:

```
if (Entries == null)
{
    ExecuteAsync(Report);                
}

if (Entries == null)
{
    RaisError("No entries!");
    return;
}
```

My problem is that the execution starts with the first if, finds it true, executes the code block and exits with Entries still equals null, and hence executes the second code block. These are ExecuteAsync and Report methods:

```
public async void ExecuteAsync(Action executeAction, Action callbackAction = null)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(executeAction);

        if (callbackAction != null)
            await Task.Run(callbackAction);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        ModernDialog.ShowMessage(exception.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtonOk);
    }
}


private void Report()
{
    Entries = DataAccessLayer.BrandReport(SelectedBrand, SelectedModel, FromDate, ToDate).ToList();

    TotalAmount = Entries.Sum(a => a.Amount);
    TotalQuantity = Entries.Sum(q => q.Quantity);
}
```

Although I am calling .ToList, I still get null in Entries!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're executing `Report` asynchronously, and then you're skipping ahead to the second if block without doing anything with the `Task` returned by `ExecuteAsync`. It stands to reason that it is possible for your second `if` to be hit before `DataAccessLayer.Brand...` has been evaluated and assigned to `Entries`.

If you want to wait for `Report` to finish before the second `Entries == null` is evaluated, either call it synchronously (i.e. without `ExecuteAsync`), or use the `Wait` method on the `Task` returned by `ExecuteAsync`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks.